# php preg_replace href attribute using conditions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

hello I have the following tags :

```
$content ='<a href="http://website.com/" />
    <a href="/link1" />
    <a href="https://website.com" />
    <a href="link1" />';
```

and this code :

```
preg_replace('~href=(\'|"|)(.*?)(\'|"|)(?<!\/|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)~i',  'href=$1http://website2.com/$2$3', $content);
```

I want to use the code above to replace href tags doesn't start with an http or https or with a slash .
 thanks in advance.

Comment: Use parser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: I'm already in 80% of my work , and my script is with regex only

Comment: so please if you can help me doing it with regex I would be thankful

Comment: I'll work up something, in your regex what was `$1` suppose to be?

Comment: $1 it's for (\'|"|) no?

Comment: kind of a hack, but could be good enough: `href=([\'"])([^/][^\'":]*)([\'"])`

Comment: Answer posted below please post if you have questions/issues.

Comment: Also, yes, you were right `$1` was for quotes of href; almost missed them on rewrite..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it. I'd advise using a parser in the future, [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php), for tasks such as this though. This can become very messy quickly. Here's a link on this regex usage as well, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.

Regex:

```
/href=("|')https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|href=("|')(.*?)\2/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cV2xB5/1

PHP Usage:

```
$content ='<a href="http://website.com/" />
    <a href="/link1" />
    <a href="https://website.com" />
    <a href="link1" />';
echo preg_replace('/href=("|\')https?:\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|href=("|\')\/?(.*?)\2/', 'href=$2http://website2.com/$3$2', $content);
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://website.com/" />
    <a href="http://website2.com/link1" />
    <a href="https://website.com" />
    <a href="http://website2.com/link1" />
```

**Update, for `//` exclusion**

Use:

```
href=("|')(?:https?:)?\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|href=("|')(.*?)\2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cV2xB5/2

PHP:

```
$content ='<a href="//website.com/" />
    <a href="/link1" />
    <a href="https://website.com" />
    <a href="link1" />';
echo preg_replace('/href=("|\')(?:https?:)?\/\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|href=("|\')\/?(.*?)\2/', 'href=$2http://website2.com/$3$2', $content);
```

Output:

```
<a href="//website.com/" />
    <a href="http://website2.com/link1" />
    <a href="https://website.com" />
    <a href="http://website2.com/link1" />
```

Comment: thanks for this , and could you please tell me how can I use it for // too

Comment: if href starts with // then don't replace it

Comment: Updated for `//` exclusion as well.

Comment: With update no longer accepted answer? Something wrong with update?

Comment: now my code works fine for all href as I wanted , but one href who starts with one slash like this <a href="/link"

Comment: don't get replaced , and yes this is good this is what I want now I want to replace href who starts with one slash with another link let's say http://website3.com/

Comment: You can't do that with this expression. You will need another expression. You could update this expression so if it starts with one `/` it doesn't get replaced. I'll leave that to you though, you should have all the information you need here. This answer answers your original question, and your additional question (2 questions with one answer!). You seem to be approaching http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Comment: ok @chris85 you helped me so much I gave you the accepted answer :)